# File content is displayed in browser window instead sending as download

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to send some content as a txt file as download but the file is opening in browser itself instead of sending as download. This is my piece of code:-

```
    StreamResource res = new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {

        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            for (String record : records)
                buf.append(record);
            ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String(buf).getBytes());
            return is;
        }
    }, filenameReport, app);
    res.setMIMEType("text/plain");
    res.getStream().setParameter("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filenameReport);
    btnGet.getWindow().open(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open window does open a window (That's why it's named that way)

Use the file `FileDownloader` class as described [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Letting+the+user+download+a+file)

The basic use is this:

```
public class LettingUserDownladFile extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Button downloadButton = new Button("Download image");

        StreamResource myResource = createResource();
        FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
        fileDownloader.extend(downloadButton);

        setContent(downloadButton);
    }

    private StreamResource createResource() {
        return new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {
            @Override
            public InputStream getStream() {
                String text = "My image";

                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(100, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                bi.getGraphics().drawChars(text.toCharArray(), 0, text.length(), 10, 20);

                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bos);
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }, "myImage.png");
    }

}
```

Comment: But my project is in vaadin 6...I can't migrate to vaadin 7 for this

Comment: Fro vaadin 6 you might try with a content type of "application/unknown"